# Compressing A .dump file

Tags: svn, compression, repository, tortoisesvn, dump

I am porting a source SVN repository to the SVN repository of our own company. I have created a .dump file of all the files inside the source repository using CMD. But the problem for me is that the size of the .dump file is too large. Is it possible to somehow reduce the size of it or compress it during or after its creation?

I haven't really found a good way to do so and we have space limit on our own repository , so I need to reduce the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Most likely, you don't need to use `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` to migrate the repository onto a new server. The repository can be copied as is into the directory with all repositories on the new server and will work just fine. E.g., use `svnadmin hotcopy` or copy the repository directory when the server services are stopped on the old server.
2. But if for some reason you are required to use `svnadmin dump`, you can try the following options to reduce the size of the file it generates:

   - Use the [`--deltas`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/#svn.ref.svnadmin.sw.deltas) option with `svnadmin dump`. You can find information about this option in SVNBook.
   - Pipe the `svnadmin dump` output into a compressed file.

PS If you are using VisualSVN Server, then read the article [KB10](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00010/#copy_from_another_location) or [use backups to move the repository](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00106/). You don't need to use `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` when migrating repositories onto VisualSVN Server in the majority of cases.

Comment: Regarding the hotcopy , it won't affect the history if I do this way , right? I'm relatively new to this subject , so I go ahead and ask another silly question. Can I use "--deltas" with svnr dump? because the repository from which I am trying to make a dump is a remote server , so I can't use svnadmin dump. If that's not possible , what would be the solution. Thanks

Comment: 1. hotcopy does not affect the original repository. It was designed for backup purposes and is absolutely safe. 2. I'm afraid that `svnrdump dump` does not support the `--deltas` option, but it supports `--incremental`. 3. If you are trying to get a copy of a remote repository, I'd suggest that you contact an admin of that remote server for assistance with obtaining a copy.